# Usage of comma vs dash

Tags: style, punctuation

Which sentence works best in regards to ',' or '-'?

> If you don't, the track record will become diluted

or

> If you don't - the track record will become diluted

Comment: Definitely the comma.

Comment: The only time I would use the dash (or more likely an ellipsis `…`) is when the statement is a threat.  A speaker would pause for emphasis, and the exaggerated orthography conveys that.

Answer (score 14):

Use the comma.   Dash denotes a break in the thought or an definition association.   Better yet, use "If you don't, then" to show that the following portion is a causal outcome of the lack of action.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely the comma, it sounds more natural and makes a softer pause in speech whereas the dash would be too sharp for this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the comma. The second clause is the direct consequence the reader is expecting to follow the first. A dash would suggest something more distinct.

Answer (score 0):

I would say in that sentence, use a comma. Or, if you wanted to expand on that sentence, you could use a semicolon (;) and say, "The track record will become diluted; and if you didn't..." and whatever you would put after that.

I hope this makes sense!